# How to throw an IOException on an InputStream method in Groovy Testing?

Tags: java, testing, groovy, inputstream, ioexception

The code (Java 11):

```
final InputStream pdfDocument = myService.generate(manifest);
final byte[] pdfDocumentBytes;
try {
  pdfDocumentBytes = pdfDocument.readAllBytes();
} catch (IOException e) {
  log.error("Unable to read content", e);
  throw new MyServiceException(MyServiceExceptionKey, MessageSeverity.ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

The test (Groovy 3.0.9):

```
def exception = {throw new IOException()}
def pdfDocument = Spy(InputStream.class)
pdfDocument.readAllBytes() >> exception
```

Alternate Test:

```
InputStream pdfDocument = Mock(InputStream.class)
PowerMockito.when(pdfDocument.readAllBytes()).thenThrow(exception)
```

The problem: I'm trying to test the exception handler in the code snip above. We're using Groovy (3.0.9 it seems) the first test doesn't raise the exception at all, and the code continues (results in an NPE later in the code). "myService" is a service that created PDF documents which are returned as an InputStream object.

The Alternate Test (which was actually what I tried initially) results in a groovy error telling me that my when() doesn't have a callable method (????) and then proceeds to give me an example that matches the code. Ugh.
Alllll I want to do is when the readAllBytes() method is called on the InputStream is to throw an IOException. Nothing more, nothing less. I've poured through a number of blogs, posts, and other sites ... and there doesn't seem to be a solution. I think if we were using JUnit rather than Groovy, the problem could be solved, but that kind of pivot at this point in the process isn't really an option - there's too many tests that would need to be converted over.

Would upgrading to a more current version help? Or are we just resigned to not being able to test that part of the code effectively?

Comment: Why not mock `myService` to return an input stream that just throws an exception?

Comment: thenThrow accepts exception class or exception instance, but not closure. https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.0/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html

Answer (score 0):

So yes using mocking is what you want to do.  However, I've had problems with Mockito + Groovy.  All of my problems were fixed by converting my tests to Java that used Mockito.  Looks like you're also using Spock which provides Mock, Stub and Spy.  For what you are trying to do I'd say you want Mock.

```
InputStream pdfDocument = Mock(InputStream.class)
pdfDocument.readAllBytes >> { throw new IOException("test test") }
myService = Mock(MyService)
myService. generate() >> pdfDocument

// test code here!
```